# Is Slavic [zima] ("winter") derived from "snow"?

Tags: etymology

I was wondering why Thai word for "snow" was sounding similar to Slavic word for "winter":

Thai: หิมะ `[hì-má]` "snow"
Ukrainian: зима `[ˈzɪ-mə]` "winter"
Polish: zima `[ˈʑi-ma]` "winter"

Also, "Himalaya" हिमालय `[himā-laya]` is commonly referred as "abode of the snow": हिम `[himā]` + आलय `[ā-laya]`.

Looking in M.Vasmer's "Etymological dictionary of Russian language", I found that Proto-Slavic `*zīmā` is related to Ancient Greek `χεῖμών`. Also, the Latin word for "winter" is `hiems`.

Despite it seems evident that Slavic word is originated from PIE, I found no sources to cite. So my question is: is it true that Slavic "zima" derived from PIE words for "snow"?

Comment: In the USA there used to be a clear, sparkling alcoholic beverage named "Zima", meant to be drunk cold, that used ice and mountains in its advertising. As a Polish speaker this used to amuse me no end.

Comment: "Zima" means also "cold". E.g. "It's cold outside" is "Venku je zima" in Czech or "Vonku je zima" in Slovak.

Comment: Zima is not derived from Greek! It is a native Slavic word.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard the phrase `zime piwo` from an American of Polish ancestry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pokorny [Etymon 632 gives](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0632.html):

- ***g̑hei**-/***g̑hi**-   'snow; winter' > ON **gamall**  'old' L **hiems**  'winter', Gk **χειμών** *kheimon* 'storm, winter'

(Note that he implies but does not explicitly include the [resultative suffix ****-(é)mn̥-**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/-mn%CC%A5) which leads to the complete forms shown.)

Pokorny does not list a Slavic reflex, but [Derksen 2008](http://books.google.com/books/about/Etymological_Dictionary_of_the_Slavic_In.html?id=LJFiAAAAMAAJ) gives **žiēmą** ‘winter’ < ***ǵheim**

So per Pokorny this semantic field includes *both* snow and winter (and Derksen concurs) and so the meaning diverged in daughter languages.

---

(Note there there is also [Pokorny Etymon ***sneigu̯h**-](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1809.html)  'to snow; snow' > Eng **snow** L **nivis** 'snow' OCS **снѣгѵ** *snĕgŭ* 'snow' Gk **νῐφάς** *niphas* 'snow, flake' Pra 'siṇeha' 'snow' which is apparently unrelated, although I suppose it could be.)

Comment: Could you clarify what language `Pkt` means? That's an abbreviation I do not know.

Comment: @Wilson I meant Prakrit, but I used the wrong abbreviation. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 9):

Wiktionary gives Thai [hima](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B0) as having Sanskrit origin, which is directly cognate to the Slavic reflex. See [this appendix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aList_of_Proto-Indo-European_roots/%C7%B5%CA%B0) for more reflexes. "Himalaya" also comes directly from Sanskrit (see that wiktionary entry). So yes, the Sanskrit reflex is squarely Indo-European.

Comment: Thank you 火星文. Yes, Thai word for "snow" has certainly derived from Sanskrit, but how do I prove that Proto-Slavic word for "winter" has the same origin? Formally, they are two different words.

Comment: Fascinating that 'zima' and 'Himalaya' actually have a common etymology!

Comment: @MarkBeadles Very this fact has inspired me to research.

Answer (score 5):

I can't offer a proof, but for what it's worth, one of the standard Croatian dictionaries, Anić's *[Rječnik hrvatskoga jezika](http://hjp.novi-liber.hr/index.php?show=search_by_id&id=f15lURh7&keyword=zima)*, gives the following etymology for Bosnian/Croatian/Serbian "zima":

prasl. i stsl. [proto-Slavic and Old Church Slavonic] zima (rus. [Russian] zimá, polj. [Polish] zima), lit. [Lithuanian] žiema ← ie. [Proto-Indo-European] *g'heym- (lat. [Latin] hiems, grč. [Classical Greek] kheȋma)"

I'm sure that any of the standard (etymological) dictionaries of any of the Slavic languages will give the same etymology.

EDIT:

As for the Thai, as Huoxingwen pointed out above, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B0) (insofar as it's to be believed) states that it's a Sanskrit loan, where the [Sanskrit original](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AE#Sanskrit) is a reflex of our old friend *g'heym-. So, to cut a long story short, the Thai word for snow seems to be a loan from Sanskrit, and the Slavic word for winter and the Sanskrit word for snow both stem from the PIE root *g'heym-.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be correct about "winter", but how is it connected to "snow"?

Comment: I guess it's only connected to "snow" insofar as PIE *g'heym- is connected to "snow" in some other Indo-European branch---the main Slavic root for "snow," which has already been mentioned above, comes from the PIE root *snoygwhos.

Comment: You've offered nothing regarding the most intriguing aspect of OP's question, which is about Thai.

Comment: @HStephenStraight I've added onto my answer, and it turns out to be nothing exciting---the Thai word is just a loan from Sanskrit, which is the very model of an Indo-European classical language...

Comment: And now I realise this is precisely the content of Huoxingwen's answer above.

Comment: Slavic word came from Sanskrit **"winter"**. Thai came from Sanskrit **"snow"**. Any evidence that Sanskrit "winter" and "snow" are the same word?

Comment: The Slavic word for winter is _zima_, the Sanskrit word for snow (which was borrowed into Thai as its word for snow) is _himaṃ_, and they both come from the PIE root *g'heym-; in particular, _zima_ is _not_ a borrowing into Slavic from Sanskrit, but is simply a cognate of _himaṃ_. Wictionary also suggests that _himaṃ_ can mean "winter" in Sanskrit, but there's no such suggestion for the Thai _hima_. What exactly are you asking here?